# Debugging website on iOS chrome

Tags: debugging, testing, mobile-development

Ive got a bug that only shows up in mobile chrome browser on my iphone - iOS8. Whats odd is that the same bug doesn't show up in iOS8 safari on the same phone.

I want to debug the issue in the chrome browser but can only find info on debugging safari, is there a way to debug ios Chrome ?

Answer (score 1):

To debug Chrome on iOS I use weinre and ngrok

Weinre will give you a local debugger on a local port
https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/

ngrok creates a proxy to a port on you comp (point to weinre)
https://ngrok.com/

then change the weinre tag to the ngrok generated one and you will get logs and the DOM while debugging remotely

Answer (score 0):

You could try to install 'Responsive Web Design Tester' extension in a Chrome browser in PC and test with the same iPhone model you have.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/responsive-web-design-tes/objclahbaimlfnbjdeobicmmlnbhamkg?hl=en

Comment: What makes Responsive Web Design Tester better than just using chrome's emulation in the dev tools?